# API Connect Test and Monitor Desktop Client

Tags: apiconnect-test-monitor

Am I able to automate and schedule tests using the APIC Test and Monitor desktop client ???

I have successfully created a working request but cant for the life of me see where I could automate and schedule this request.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the auto generation feature of the [IBM API Connect test and monitor](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/api-connect/api-test) is not currently available for the desktop app.

However, there are plans to integrate this feature into the desktop app in the future.

**Disclaimer**: I'm a member of the IBM API Connect Test and Monitor development team.

Comment: Hi, 

Has there been any progress on the Desktop App to add any functionality available in the cloud hosted version ?

Regards,

Brian